# If $f$ is a diffeomorphism, why is $p(X|Y=y) = p(X|Z=f^{-1}(y))$, i.e., conditioning on $Z=f^{-1}(y)$ is the same as conditioning on $Y=y$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I read in a paper that if $f$, a function, is a **diffeomorphism**, meaning that: 1) It is a differentiable function, and 2) its inverse transformation $f^{-1}$ is also differentiable, then for random variables $X, Y, Z$:

$$
p(X|Y=y) = p(X|Z=f^{-1}(y))
$$

in that conditioning on $Z=f^{-1}(y)$ is the same as conditioning on $Y=y$. It appears that the sigma algebra generated by the events are the same, but I am not sure how to prove nor see this formally, does anyone see anything I can do? Thanks.

Comment: If Y is discrete, this is direct. If Y is continuous, one has to rely on the measure theoretical definition of conditional distributions. What happened when you applied it?

Comment: If $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are completely unrelated your question makes no sense to me. Something is missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that $ X, Y $ and $ Z = f ( Y) $ are real valued random variables you
have to prove that for $ B \in \mathscr{B}_{ \mathbb{R}}$, $ \mathbb{P} ( X \in
B | Z =  f^{-1} ( .)  ) \circ Y$ is a version of the conditional probability $
\mathbb{P} ( X \in B | Y) = \mathbb{E} \left( \mathbf{1}_{ B} \circ X | Y
\right) $. However, for $ C \in \mathscr{B}_{ \mathbb{R}}$
\begin{align*}
  & \ \ \ \
  \int_{ \left\{ 
      Y \in C
  \right\} }^{ } 
  \mathbb{P} ( X \in B | Z = f^{-1} ( .)  ) \circ Y 
  \, d \mathbb{P} 
  = \int_{ \left\{ 
      Y \in C
    \right\} }^{ } 
    \mathbb{P} ( X \in B | Z = f^{-1} ( Y)  )
    \, d \mathbb{P} \\ 
  & 
  = \int_{ \left\{ 
      Y \in C
    \right\} }^{ } 
    \mathbb{P} ( X \in B | Z )
    \, d \mathbb{P} 
  = \int_{ \left\{ 
      Y \in C
    \right\} }^{ } 
    \mathbb{P} ( X \in B | \sigma ( Z)   )
    \, d \mathbb{P}
  = \int_{ \left\{ 
      Y \in C
    \right\} }^{ } 
    \mathbb{P} ( X \in B | \sigma ( Y)   )
    \, d \mathbb{P} \\ 
  & 
  = \int_{ \left\{ 
      Y \in C
    \right\} }^{ } 
    \mathbb{P} ( X \in B | Y  )
    \, d \mathbb{P} 
  = \mathbb{P} ( \left\{ X \in B , Y \in C \right\})  ,
\end{align*}
which is just the defining property of $ \mathbb{E} ( \mathbf{1}_{ B} ( X) | Y
) $.